# transfer file selected in form with scp/sftp

Tags: php, forms, sftp, scp

I'd like to upload file from html form through scp/sftp (I know their syntax) in php script, not the traditional way (upload to server's /tmp folder, then calling         `move_uploaded_file`)    . Upon submitting the form, I'd just like to fetch the uploaded file's full path from     `<input type="file"...>`    and pass it into     `ssh2_scp_send`    .

If there is a way please let me know, if not, please explain why.

Btw, if there is a way to select in web page where the user wants to upload the file on server (some gui/dialog), let me know too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the server side from the client side. The web page (client side) is generally not able to upload anything anywhere directly (without use of some plugin or applet - Java applet would work fine). PHP itself, being a server-side language (in general, I am ignoring border cases now) can't be used to directly transfer the file from user's computer to some SFTP server.

So the best option is to let the user upload the file to the HTTP server as a part of the form, then upload the received file to the SFTP server. If you can't do this (eg. due to size limitations), you can create a Java applet which will let the user choose the file and transfer it to the server.